# Import Record Type in Clojure/ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there any way to import a record type, that works in Clojure as well as ClojureScript?
As far as I can tell it's `(ns x (:import y [A B]))` for Clojure, `(ns x (:require y :refer [A B]))` for ClojureScript, and each is invalid for the respective other.

Comment: `import` in CLJS in *only* used for Google Closure classes. Clojure's import is *only* for Java classes. So I'm not sure what you're trying to solve? Can you give a specific questions? With specific files and things you want to import?

Comment: @estolua is using `import` in Clojure and `require` in ClojureScript.

Comment: Running into the same issue, so to reply to the "what are you trying to solve" comment: in my case there's clojure/clojurescript code in cljc files, with some defrecords. The other namespaces need to "import" the record type for clojure, but "require" it for clojurescript. Or in short: "Clojure's import is only for Java classes" isn't accurate; it's also needed for importing records defined in clojure. By the way, it should be no big deal using reader conditionals (will try that now and will reply if it didn't work), but it would be nicer if that weren't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the specifics on the syntax of requiring records, there are two main ways to write ns declarations (or any platform specific code) for multiple Clojure variants while sharing the majority of your code.

1. [CLJX](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx) is a Clojure preprocessor that runs before the Clojure compiler. You write platform specific code prefixed with `#+clj` or `#+cljs` in a `.cljx` file. It can run on pretty much any Clojure code, and will spit out multiple platform specific files which the respective Clojure Compilers can handle.
2. [Reader Conditionals](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Reader+Conditionals) are a feature in Clojure 1.7 and are available in recent releases of ClojureScript. This is similar in spirit to cljx, but is integrated into the Clojure Compiler. You write code with reader conditionals like `#?(:clj 1 :cljs 2)` in files with a `.cljc` extension.

Now back to your specific question, you can achieve this with Reader Conditionals like so:

```
(ns myapp.music-store
  (:require #?(:clj [myapp.cool-music]
               :cljs [myapp.cool-music :refer [Vinyl]]))
  #?(:clj
     (:import [myapp.cool_music Vinyl])))
```

I wrote a longer blog post about this too: [Requiring records in Clojure and ClojureScript](https://danielcompton.net/2016/05/04/requiring-records-clojure-clojurescript)